# How to count each entry from each column corresponding to a search term

Tags: perl

I have a input file like this (3 column data). Different entries are also present in each rows.. corresponding to a .. b .. and c ...

```
a   sk  asd                 
a   sk  lsd                 
a   mk  wsd                 
a   lk  asd                 
a   lk  lsd                 
a   pk  wsd                 
a   pk  asd                 
b   sk  lsd                 
b   sk  wsd                 
b   mk  asd                 
b   lk  lsd                 
b   lk  wsd                 
c   sk  asd                 
c   sk  lsd                 
c   mk  wsd                 
c   lk  asd                 
c   lk  lsd                 
d   sk  wsd                 
d   sk  asd                 
d   mk  lsd
```

I want to write a perl program, which, first count a, b, c and d. and then count each entries corresponding to a, b, c and d.

Output will be like this..

```
a=7 sk=2    mk=1    lk=2    pk=2    asd=3   lsd=2   wsd=2    
b=5 sk=2    mk=1    lk=2    pk=0    asd=1   lsd=2   wsd=2    
c=5 sk=2    mk=1    lk=2    pk=0    asd=2   lsd=2   wsd=1
d=3 sk=2    mk=1    lk=0    pk=0    asd=1   lsd=1   wsd=1
```

How I can make this. Please help ?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

my %count_elements_of;
my %count_of;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ( $term, @things ) = split;
    $count_of{$term}++;
    foreach my $thing (@things) {
        $count_elements_of{$term}{$thing}++;
    }
}

foreach my $term ( sort keys %count_elements_of ) {
    print "$term => $count_of{$term}, ";
    foreach my $thing ( sort keys %{ $count_elements_of{$term} } ) {
        print "$thing => $count_elements_of{$term}{$thing}, ";
    }
    print "\n";
}


__DATA__
a sk asd
a sk lsd
a mk wsd
a lk asd
a lk lsd
a pk wsd
a pk asd
b sk lsd
b sk wsd
b mk asd
b lk lsd
b lk wsd
c sk asd
c sk lsd
c mk wsd
c lk asd
c lk lsd
d sk wsd
d sk asd
d mk lsd
```

Which will print:

```
a => 7, asd => 3, lk => 2, lsd => 2, mk => 1, pk => 2, sk => 2, wsd => 2, 
b => 5, asd => 1, lk => 2, lsd => 2, mk => 1, sk => 2, wsd => 2, 
c => 5, asd => 2, lk => 2, lsd => 2, mk => 1, sk => 2, wsd => 1, 
d => 3, asd => 1, lsd => 1, mk => 1, sk => 2, wsd => 1,
```

To explain - what you need is hashes, which are really one of perl's 'killer features'. We have two in the example above, because you want to count two different things - occurrences of the *first* letter, and occurrences of each of the sub elements within that letter prefix.

- So we run through each line of `DATA` (you probably want to use a real filehandle here).
- We use `split` to turn the line into an array, delimited by spaces.
- We assign the first element to `$term` and all the other things on the line into `@things`.
- iterate the `@things` list, and update the total count within a particular letter, and also the per prefix/letter `%count_elements_of` hash.
- And then we iterate the keys of our hashes (sorting them) and printing the results.

What we don't do in the above, is handle completely missing keys particularly well. If you want to do that, you can't use `keys` on the hash any more - because 'not present' is 'undefined'.

So instead, you need to:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

my %count_elements_of;
my %count_of;
my %all_sub_elements; 

while (<DATA>) {
    my ( $term, @things ) = split;
    $count_of{$term}++;
    foreach my $thing (@things) {
        $count_elements_of{$term}{$thing}++;
        $all_sub_elements{$thing}++; 
    }
}

foreach my $term ( sort keys %count_elements_of ) {
    print "$term => $count_of{$term}, ";
    foreach my $thing ( sort keys %all_sub_elements ) {
        print "$thing => ", $count_elements_of{$term}{$thing} // 0," ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

This will 'build up' a list of all the things that might need printing in `%all_sub_elements` which we use later to figure out what to output. We use the `//` operator, which is a conditional *similar* to `||` (logical or) but is for `defined`. It doesn't make much difference in this case, but I think it's a useful distinction when operating on hashes normally. (Because as hash with a value of zero isn't the same as one with a missing value).

Which then prints:

```
a => 7, asd => 3 lk => 2 lsd => 2 mk => 1 pk => 2 sk => 2 wsd => 2 
b => 5, asd => 1 lk => 2 lsd => 2 mk => 1 pk => 0 sk => 2 wsd => 2 
c => 5, asd => 2 lk => 2 lsd => 2 mk => 1 pk => 0 sk => 2 wsd => 1 
d => 3, asd => 1 lk => 0 lsd => 1 mk => 1 pk => 0 sk => 2 wsd => 1
```

You could - alternatively - define an array:

```
my @output_order = qw ( sk lk mk asd lsd wsd );
```

And instead use that for the ordering of your output if you prefer:

```
foreach my $thing ( @output_order ) {
```

etc.

Comment: thanks a lot. Its working !! What about the split , if we have \t delimited data ??

Comment: `split` defaults to 'any whitespace'. http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html so it will work for tabs. But if you want _just_ tabs, then `split /\t/;` will do the trick.

Comment: Now, I want only the numbers, not the things's name. What I have to do ??

Comment: remove `"$thing => ",` from the print statement.

Comment: Its fine. Its a great help from your side. Now, I have a different question.

Comment: Please give your EMAIL id. I want to contact you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not inclined to give out my email ID. If you have a different question, then the appropriate course would be to post a new question.